# What will happen if HTTP request happens and the intrent connection is lost?

Tags: http, httpclient

Suppose we are requesting though `http client` at the middle if internet connection is lost them what will happen.

Suppose we are using android java

Comment: What language/platform are you asking about?

Comment: in short, "Human sacrifice, dogs and cats living together... mass hysteria!" Well, no, not really, but it all comes down to how the app(s) on either end are coded and how they handle network disconnects.

Comment: @MarcB what do you mean in your first statement !!

Comment: @Bader - it's a joke - he means that that society will collapse if we lose internet connections.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on the [specific OSI layer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model) you are interested in.
In most cases the client-side libraries implement (or are expected to implement) *TCP timeout* error.

Answer (score 1):

HTTP is a state less. So depending on what the software is a making the request, it will not receive a reply. So it must decide what to do and when.